# Cropping Image with Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to crop an image on the fly using canvas and get the base64 string to load into an element.  I was working with the example from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015497/how-to-resize-then-crop-an-image-with-canvas) but when I run .toDataURL() the base64 I am getting is truncated and invalid.

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cj3995w/1/)

```
var image = new Image(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,
        70, 20,   // Start at 70/20 pixels from the left and the top of the image (crop),
        50, 50,   // "Get" a `50 * 50` (w * h) area from the source image (crop),
        0, 0,     // Place the result at 0, 0 in the canvas,
        50, 50); // With as width / height: 100 * 100 (scale)
}

image.src = 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png';

var _img = document.getElementById('base64');
_img.innerHTML += canvas.toDataURL();
```

From the toDataURL I am only getting 552 characters of base64.  When I save the cropped image and decode the image to base64 it is around 3.8k characters.

I can't see what I am doing wrong - any ideas?

Comment: The result of [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) is _**image data**_, not HTML. It cannot be assigned to element's innerHTML. On client side it is only appropriate to be assigned to image's `src` attribute.

Comment: The result of toDataUrl is base64 which absolutely can be assigned to the innerHTML as I have a working example of this.

Answer (score -1):

So, as usual I didn't have an epiphany until after I posted this in public. Go figure.

Two problems

1. I was getting a short base64 string because that was being generated before the image had actually loaded into the canvas.
2. Once that was fixed I got the error

   Tainted canvases may not be exported.

Which I fixed (using a different image hosted on imgur - the google image still threw the error) by adding

```
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
```

Corrected code:

```
var image = new Image(),
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

image.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(image,
        70, 20,   // Start at 70/20 pixels from the left and the top of the image (crop),
        50, 50,   // "Get" a `50 * 50` (w * h) area from the source image (crop),
        0, 0,     // Place the result at 0, 0 in the canvas,
        50, 50); // With as width / height: 100 * 100 (scale)
    var _img = document.getElementById('base64');
    _img.innerHTML += canvas.toDataURL();
}

image.src = 'https://www.google.nl/images/srpr/logo3w.png';
```

Comment: The canvas is already 50 by 50 so no need to use the long signature `drawImage`  just offset the image `ctx.drawImage(image,-70,-20)` also it is best to set object properties directly eg `image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";`

Comment: I actually tried not using the long signature but it would not draw without specifying the 0,0 draw position and the size