# Crop the image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, html5-canvas

In my Angular 6 application I am making a file upload option and in preview the uploaded file needs to be displayed with auto cropping and auto resizing.

I have tried the following,

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" [src]="url" width="300" height="227">
</div>
<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
```

**File select functtion:**

```
  onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
        this.url = event.target.result;
      }

      const canvas : any =  document.getElementById('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const image = document.getElementById('source');

      ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
    }
  }
```

In the above I have tried the following with the reference of link https://jsfiddle.net/8jwq3cs7/

```
      const canvas : any =  document.getElementById('canvas');
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      const image = document.getElementById('source');

      ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
```

Before using the canvas the original image looks like this: https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg

Whereas after using canvas it's like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8jwq3cs7/

But if I choose the image from `choose file` then I am **unable to see the image** after choosing...

**Working example:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-uwpf8f

Even the solution with pure JavaScript alone would also be appreciable if not in the Angular way...

**The requirement is,** if I choose a file then the same file needs to be cropped and fit the size automatically in preview...

Kindly help me to achieve the result **without jQuery or any library**...

Comment: Don't forget to implement EXIF orientation tag correction to correct for mobile photo orientation.

Comment: @Rik,Sorry i am unable to get you.. Please help me to crop and resize the choosen image..

Comment: Do you want to crop it to the "animals"-face or just in a particular size, like background-size: cover?

Comment: @undefined If your script will show previews of JPEG images they will be rotated incorrectly when they have EXIF orientation tag (which is the case when the pictures are taken on mobile phones). So you'll have to read out the tag and rotate your canvas context accordingly. https://medium.com/@Orangeeli/oh-my-exif-777335e26213

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image crop and resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811160/image-crop-and-resize)

Comment: [Reffer this question. I think this is the best option for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015497/how-to-resize-then-crop-an-image-with-canvas)

Answer (score 15):

Here is a function to get the image as you are uploading using the **choose file** button

```js
function readURL() {
    const myimg = document.getElementById("myimg");
    const input = document.getElementById("myfile");
    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => {
            console.log("changed");
            myimg.src = e.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
document.querySelector('#myfile').addEventListener('change', () => {
    readURL();
});
```

And the HTML will be

```html
<img src="" id="myimg"><br>
<input type="file" id="myfile">
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geongeorgek/og6adnhk/8/)

If you add a file the preview image will be updated.
You actually get a data url here. Use the data url to the load the image to the canvas then crop it. calling `drawimg(e.target.result)`

```js
function drawimg(idata) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);
    };
    img.src = idata;
}
```

See working Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/geongeorgek/rp0bym1a/)

Comment: I just used jquery so I could do the .change() function easily. There isn't much jquery involved in this. Just read before you downvote

Comment: Hello dear it is angular application, here we won't use jquery at any case even it may small or big.. It is strictly restricted to use jquery.. If i need jquery then i wouldn't post this question..

Comment: @undefined now I have edited the answer. You haven't even read the answer properly before you went to downvote. The code was and is still working. I used jquery only on the part to identify file change event. Now it's entirely vanilla js

Comment: I think you haven't got my question well.. I am in the need of croping of uploaded image.. Read it carefully..

Comment: Your closing sentence - "*Use the data url to the load image to canvas then crop it*" - is the question that the OP seems to be asking; can you expand upon that to show *how* that might be accomplished? Also please remember to explain your answers in order that people can learn from you.

Comment: @undefined Here is the  full working version: https://jsfiddle.net/geongeorgek/8jwq3cs7/14/

Comment: @undefined Oops a change was not saved. Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/geongeorgek/rp0bym1a/

Comment: So you want the user to select the face region or auto detect faces? either way you framed the question wrong or I'm sorry for misreading it

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I implemented it in my case:

```
  onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url

      reader.onload = (event) => { // called once readAsDataURL is completed
       console.log(event);
        this.url = event.target.result;
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = this.url;

        ctx.drawImage(image, 33, 71, 104, 124, 21, 20, 87, 104);

      }
```

The working stackblitz demo is here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-qrrgx5

Hope it helps and this is what you want.

Comment: My requirement needs to be like, if i upload my picture that has 500px in height and 500px in width then i need to resize it with displaying the face alone with auto crop and auto resize.I hope you got it that i am uploading image for profile picture then it automatically crop the face area alone and displaying it.. I am expecting auto crop of face area alone in the profile image we upload..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party on this one, but I was facing a very similar issue myself yesterday, but instead using NodeJS.

My solution in the end was to break down the image into its RGBA values and check each row and column of the image to find where the image itself actually starts in comparison to the BG.

In my case, I'm working with images that are around 1500px*500px, with my solution taking around 150-250ms per image to read in the file, break down its pixels, calculate the cropping positions and to write the cropped file back to disk.

Since I couldn't find any nice libraries online to handle this, I've made my own and published it to NPM in case anyone else comes across the same issue and needs some help! :-)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/developyn-autocrop

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #preview {
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid green;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v0.9.12/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jcrop-cdn.tapmodo.com/v0.9.12/css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).delegate(':file', 'change', function() {
            picture(this);
            console.log('running');
        });

         //$(document).delegate(':form', 'change', function() {

        var picture_width;
        var picture_height;
        var crop_max_width = 300;
        var crop_max_height = 300;
        function picture(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $("#jcrop, #preview").html("").append("<img src=\""+e.target.result+"\" alt=\"\" />");
                    picture_width = $("#preview img").width();
                    picture_height = $("#preview img").height();
                    $("#jcrop  img").Jcrop({
                        onChange: canvas,
                        onSelect: canvas,
                        boxWidth: crop_max_width,
                        boxHeight: crop_max_height
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
        function canvas(coords){
            var imageObj = $("#jcrop img")[0];
            var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
            canvas.width  = coords.w;
            canvas.height = coords.h;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(imageObj, coords.x, coords.y, coords.w, coords.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            png();
        }
        function png() {
            var png = $("#canvas")[0].toDataURL('image/png');
            $("#png").val(png);
        }
        function dataURLtoBlob(dataURL) {
            var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
            if(dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
                var parts = dataURL.split(',');
                var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
                var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);

                return new Blob([raw], {type: contentType});
            }
            var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
            var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
            var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
            var rawLength = raw.length;
            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
            for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return new Blob([uInt8Array], {type: contentType});
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <form id="form">
        <h2>Image file select</h2>
        <input id="file" type="file" onchange="imageLoad()" />
        <h2>Uploaded Image</h2>
        <div id="jcrop"></div>
        <h2>Cropped Image</h2>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <input id="png" type="hidden" />
        <h2>Submit form</h2>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload form data and image" />
       </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Providing code is good but some explanation too of why your code works and what mistakes the person asking the question was making will help people understand your answer. [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23549465)

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Set constraints for the video stream
var constraints = { video: { facingMode: "user" }, audio: false };
// Define constants
const cameraView = document.querySelector("#camera--view"),
    cameraOutput = document.querySelector("#camera--output"),
    cameraSensor = document.querySelector("#camera--sensor"),
    cameraTrigger = document.querySelector("#camera--trigger")
// Access the device camera and stream to cameraView
function cameraStart() {
    navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then(function(stream) {
        track = stream.getTracks()[0];
        cameraView.srcObject = stream;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Oops. Something is broken.", error);
    });
}
// Take a picture when cameraTrigger is tapped
cameraTrigger.onclick = function() {
    cameraSensor.width = cameraView.videoWidth;
    cameraSensor.height = cameraView.videoHeight;
    cameraSensor.getContext("2d").drawImage(cameraView, 0, 0);
    cameraOutput.src = cameraSensor.toDataURL("image/webp");
    cameraOutput.classList.add("taken");
};
// Start the video stream when the window loads
window.addEventListener("load", cameraStart, false);
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#camera, #camera--view, #camera--sensor, #camera--output{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
#camera--view, #camera--sensor, #camera--output{
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
}
#camera--trigger{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
}
.taken{
    height: 100px!important;
    width: 100px!important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    border: solid 3px white;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html lang=”en”>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Name of your awesome camera app -->
    <title>Camera App</title>
    <!-- Link to your main style sheet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <main id="camera">
        <!-- Camera sensor -->
        <canvas id="camera--sensor"></canvas>
        <!-- Camera view -->
        <video id="camera--view" autoplay playsinline></video>
        <!-- Camera output -->
        <img src="//:0" alt="" id="camera--output">
        <!-- Camera trigger -->
        <button id="camera--trigger">Take a picture</button>
    </main>
    <!-- Reference to your JavaScript file -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some expalinations.

Comment: `Error: Oops. Something is broken.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this JavaScript Code.

Source code: [Image Cropper](https://jsfeed.io/code/51e87t5oi5/image-cropper-with-download-button)

**JavaScript**

```
    $w = $(window);
$d = $(document);

(function(y) {
    y.ImageCropper = function(z, y, E) {
        function A(b) {
            F();
            t.show();
            t.addClass("notransition");
            c.addClass("notransition");
            t[0].offsetHeight;
            c[0].offsetHeight;
            t.removeClass("notransition");
            c.removeClass("notransition");
            t.addClass("icrop-transition");
            c.addClass("icrop-transition");
            b ? B.setVals(b.x, b.y, b.w, b.h) : B.setVals(0, 0, c.width(), c.height());
            clearTimeout(G);
            G = setTimeout(function() {
                t.removeClass("icrop-transition");
                c.removeClass("icrop-transition")
            }, 1E3)
        }

        function C() {
            var b = Math.min(y, u.width()),
                a;
            n / p > b / E ? a = b / n * p : (a = E, b = a / p * n);
            q.css({
                width: b,
                height: a
            });
            c.css({
                width: b,
                height: a
            });
            q[0].width = n;
            q[0].height = p;
            c[0].width = n;
            c[0].height = p;
            H(q[0], I, d, e);
            H(c[0], M, d, e);
            F()
        }

        function H(b, a, m, l) {
            a.clearRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
            a.translate(b.width / 2, b.height / 2);
            var h = 90 === l || 270 === l;
            a.scale(v && !h || w && h ? -1 : 1, w && !h || v && h ? -1 : 1);
            0 < l ? (a.rotate(l / 180 * Math.PI), 180 === l ? (a.translate(-b.width / 2, -b.height / 2), a.drawImage(m, 0, 0, b.width, b.height), a.translate(b.width / 2, b.height / 2)) : (a.translate(-b.height / 2, -b.width /
                2), a.drawImage(m, 0, 0, b.height, b.width), a.translate(b.height / 2, b.width / 2)), a.rotate(-l / 180 * Math.PI)) : a.drawImage(m, -b.width / 2, -b.height / 2, b.width, b.height);
            a.scale(1, 1);
            a.translate(-b.width / 2, -b.height / 2)
        }

        function F() {
            N.height(q.height()).width(q.width())
        }

        function O(b) {
            var a = n,
                m = p,
                l = I.getImageData(0, 0, a, m).data,
                h, k = [r(l, a, 0, 0), r(l, a, a - 1, 0), r(l, a, a - 1, l.length / 4 / a - 1), r(l, a, 0, l.length / 4 / a - 1)];
            h = {};
            for (var g = 0; g < k.length; g++) {
                var c = k[g].r + "," + k[g].b + "," + k[g].g + "," + k[g].a;
                h[c] = h[c] ? h[c] + 1 : 1
            }
            var k = 0,
                g = "",
                d;
            for (d in h) h.hasOwnProperty(d) && h[d] > k && (k = h[d], g = d);
            g = g.split(",");
            h = g = {
                r: g[0],
                g: g[1],
                b: g[2],
                a: g[3]
            };
            k = d = 0;
            g = a;
            c = m;
            d = 0;
            a: for (; d < a; d++) {
                for (var e = k; e < m; e++) {
                    var f = x(h, r(l, a, d, e));
                    if (1024 < f) break a
                }
                g--
            }
            k = 0;
            a: for (; k < m; k++) {
                for (e = d; e < a; e++)
                    if (f = x(h, r(l, a, e, k)), 1024 < f) break a;
                c--
            }
            g;
            a: for (; 0 < g; g--)
                for (e = k; e < k + c; e++)
                    if (f = x(h, r(l, a, d + g, e)), 1024 < f) break a;
            c;
            a: for (; 0 < c; c--)
                for (e = d; e < d + g; e++)
                    if (f = x(h, r(l, a, e, k + c)), 1024 < f) break a;
            return 0 === g || 0 === c ? {
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                w: a,
                h: m
            } : {
                x: Math.max(0, d - b),
                y: Math.max(0, k - b),
                w: Math.max(0,
                    Math.min(a, g + 2 * b)),
                h: Math.max(0, Math.min(m, c + 2 * b))
            }
        }

        function r(b, a, d, e) {
            a = a * e + d;
            return {
                r: b[4 * a],
                g: b[4 * a + 1],
                b: b[4 * a + 2],
                a: b[4 * a + 3]
            }
        }

        function x(b, a) {
            return (b.r - a.r) * (b.r - a.r) + (b.g - a.g) * (b.g - a.g) + (b.b - a.b) * (b.b - a.b) + (b.a - a.a) * (b.a - a.a)
        }
        z = $(z);
        var u = $('<div class="icrop-wrap"><canvas class="icrop-preview-canv"></canvas><div class="icrop-bg"></div><div class="icrop-box" style="position:absolute"><div class="icrop-clip-wrap"><canvas class="icrop-clip-canv"></canvas></div></div>'),
            t = u.find(".icrop-box"),
            N = u.find(".icrop-bg"),
            q = u.find(".icrop-preview-canv"),
            c = u.find(".icrop-clip-canv");
        z.html(u);
        var D, f = this,
            n, p, e = 0,
            w = !1,
            v = !1,
            d = new Image,
            J = "",
            K = 0,
            L = "",
            B = new Dragger(t, c, function(b, a, d, e) {
                b = parseInt(b);
                a = parseInt(a);
                c.css({
                    left: -b,
                    top: -a
                });
                D && D()
            }),
            I = q[0].getContext("2d"),
            M = c[0].getContext("2d");
        f.getFilename = function() {
            return J
        };
        f.getTemplateId = function() {
            return K
        };
        f.getOriginalUrl = function() {
            return L
        };
        f.setMoveCallback = function(b) {
            D = b
        };
        f.setSrc = function(b, a, c, f) {
            e = 0;
            v = w = !1;
            $(d).off("load").on("load", function() {
                n = d.naturalWidth;
                p = d.naturalHeight;
                C();
                A()
            });
            d.src = b;
            J = a;
            K = ~~c;
            L = f || ""
        };
        f.getFinalDataUrl = function(b) {
            var a;
            a = f.getVals();
            a = 0 !== a.x || 0 !== a.y || a.w !== d.naturalWidth || a.h !== d.naturalHeight || 0 !== e || w || v ? !0 : !1;
            if (!a && "data:" === d.src.substr(0, 5)) return d.src;
            a = f.getVals();
            var c = $("<canvas>").attr({
                width: a.w,
                height: a.h
            });
            c[0].getContext("2d").drawImage(q[0], a.x, a.y, a.w, a.h, 0, 0, a.w, a.h);
            return c[0].toDataURL(b)
        };
        f.setVals = function(b) {
            var a = c.width() / (90 === e || 270 === e ? d.naturalHeight : d.naturalWidth);
            A({
                x: Math.round(b.x * a),
                y: Math.round(b.y * a),
                w: Math.round(b.w * a),
                h: Math.round(b.h * a)
            })
        };
        f.getVals = function() {
            var b = (90 === e || 270 === e ? d.naturalHeight : d.naturalWidth) / c.width(),
                a = (90 === e || 270 === e ? d.naturalWidth : d.naturalHeight) / c.height(),
                f = B.getVals();
            return {
                x: Math.round(f.x * b),
                y: Math.round(f.y * a),
                w: Math.round(f.w * b),
                h: Math.round(f.h * a)
            }
        };
        /*f.autoCrop = function(b) {
            f.setVals(O(b))
        };*/
        f.rotateClockwise = function() {
            e = 270 === e ? 0 : e + 90;
            var b = n;
            n = p;
            p = b;
            C();
            A()
        };
        f.flipHorizontal = function() {
            90 === e || 270 === e ? w = !w : v = !v;
            C()
        };
        var G
    }
})(window);

(function(d, aa, v, D, ia) {

    function pa(a) {
        a.css({
            height: 0
        });
        var b = parseInt(a.css("borderTopWidth")) + a[0].scrollHeight + parseInt(a.css("borderBottomWidth"));
        a.css({
            height: b
        })
    }

    function ba(a, b, c, e, u) {
        b = b || 100;
        u = qa && u;
        var p, B, l, d, h, g, v = function() {
            var C = +new Date;
            C - d < b && (!e || C - h < e) && !u ? p = setTimeout(v, b - (C - d)) : (p = null, c || (g = a.apply(l, B), l = B = null))
        };
        return function() {
            l = this;
            B = arguments;
            d = +new Date;
            h || (h = +new Date);
            var e = c && !p;
            p || (p = u ? qa(v) : setTimeout(v, b));
            e && (g = a.apply(l, B), l = B = null);
            return g
        }
    }

    function K(a) {
        a = a || d.event;
        a.stopPropagation && a.stopPropagation();
        a.preventDefault && a.preventDefault();
        a.cancelBubble = !0;
        a.cancel = !0;
        return a.returnValue = !1
    }
    
    d.Dragger = function(a, b, c, d) {
        function h(a, n, b, f, Z, d) {
            k = a;
            m = n;
            r = b;
            t = f;
            Z !== ia && null !== Z && (w = Z, J = Math.floor((w + 90) / 360));
            a = w ? "rotate(" + w + "deg)" : "";
            c && c(k, m, r, t, w);
            n = {
                transform: a,
                left: ~~k - 1,
                top: ~~m - 1,
                width: ~~r,
                height: ~~t
            };
            d && (n.transform += (w ? " " : "") + "scale3d(0,0,0)");
            z.css(n);
            d && (z.css({
                transition: "1s",
                transform: a + (w ? " " : "") + "scale3d(1,1,1)"
            }), setTimeout(function() {
                z.css({
                    transition: ""
                })
            }, 1500))
        }

        function p(a) {
            K(a);
            y = O.width();
            x = O.height();
            M = r;
            N = t;
            P = k;
            A = m;
            Y = a.clientX;
            R = a.clientY;
            Z = -Math.sin(w / 180 * Math.PI) * (t / 2 + 20);
            n = -Math.cos(w / 180 * Math.PI) * (t / 2 + 20);
            $("body").addClass("nosel");
            D.on("vmousemove", B).on("vmouseup", H);
            10 === q && (L || (L = $('<div class="drag-rotate-msg">'), z.parent().append(L)), v(), L.show())
        }

        function B(a) {
            if (q) {
                E = a.clientX - Y;
                F = a.clientY - R;
                k = P;
                m = A;
                1 === q && (k = P + E, m = A + F, C && 0 === w % 360 ? (0 > k ? k = 0 : k + r > y && (k = y - r), 0 > m ? m = 0 : m + t > x && (m = x - t)) : (k + r < g ? k = g - r : k > y - g && (k = y - g), m + t < g ? m = g - t : m > x - g && (m = x - g)), C || 0 !== w % 180 || (3 > Math.abs(k) ?
                    k = 0 : 3 > Math.abs(k + r - y) && (k = y - r), 3 > Math.abs(m) ? m = 0 : 3 > Math.abs(m + t - x) && (m = x - t)));
                if (10 === q) {
                    var b = n - F;
                    a = Math.atan((Z + E) / b) / Math.PI * 180;
                    var f = Math.abs(a % 90);
                    if (2 > f || 88 < f) a = 90 * Math.round(a / 90);
                    0 < b && (a += 180);
                    b = (w - 360 * J) % 360; - 90 <= a && 0 > a && 270 >= b && 180 < b ? J++ : -90 <= b && 0 > b && 270 >= a && 180 < a && J--;
                    w = a + 360 * J;
                    v()
                }
                a = 0 === w % 360;
                a || (b = l(E, F, -w), E = b.x, F = b.y);
                if (G)
                    if (6 === q || 8 === q) E = Math.round(G * F);
                    else if (7 === q || 9 === q) E = -Math.round(G * F);
                var c = f = b = !1,
                    d = !1;
                if (2 === q || 6 === q || 7 === q) m = A + F, t = N - F, C && a ? 0 > m && (m = 0, t = N + A) : m + t < g ? t = g - m :
                    m > x - g && (m = x - g, t = N + A - m), t < g && (t = g, m = A + N - g), !C && a && 3 > Math.abs(m) && (t += m, m = 0, b = 6 === q, c = 2 !== q);
                else if (4 === q || 8 === q || 9 === q) t = N + F, C && a ? m + t > x && (t = x - m) : t < g - m && (t = g - m), t < g && (t = g), !C && a && 3 > Math.abs(m + t - x) && (t = x - m, b = 9 === q, c = 4 !== q);
                if (5 === q || 6 === q || 9 === q) k = P + E, r = M - E, C && a ? 0 > k && (k = 0, r = M + P) : k + r < g ? r = g - k : k > y - g && (k = y - g, r = M + P - k), r < g && (r = g, k = P + M - g), !C && a && 3 > Math.abs(k) && (r += k, k = 0, f = 6 === q, d = 5 !== q);
                else if (3 === q || 7 === q || 8 === q) r = M + E, C && a ? k + r > y && (r = y - k) : r < g - k && (r = g - k), r < g && (r = g), !C && a && 3 > Math.abs(k + r - y) && (r = y - k, f = 7 === q,
                    d = 3 !== q);
                G && (c && (b && (k += r - Math.round(G * t)), r = G * t), d && (f && (m += t - Math.round(r / G)), t = r / G));
                a || 1 === q || 10 === q || (a = k - P + (r - M) / 2, b = m - A + (t - N) / 2, k -= a, m -= b, b = l(a, b, w), k += b.x, m += b.y);
                h(k, m, r, t, w)
            }
        }

        function l(a, b, n) {
            var f = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
            b = f ? Math.asin(b / f) : 0;
            0 > a && (b = Math.PI - b);
            b += n / 180 * Math.PI;
            return {
                x: Math.cos(b) * f,
                y: Math.sin(b) * f
            }
        }

        function v() {
            L.text("rotation: " + Math.round(10 * w) / 10 + "\u00b0")
        }

        function H() {
            10 === q && L.hide();
            q = 0;
            G && (G = r / t);
            $("body").removeClass("nosel");
            D.off("vmouseup", H)
        }
        d = d || {};
        var g = d.minWidth ||
            20,
            Q = !0,
            C = d.enforceBoundary !== ia ? d.enforceBoundary : !0,
            z = $(a),
            O = $(b),
            L, k = 0,
            m = 0,
            r = g,
            t = g,
            w = 0,
            J = 0,
            G, P, A, M, N, q, E, F, y, x, Y, R, Z, n, f = "N E S W NW NE SE SW".split(" ");
        a = "";
        for (b = 0; b < f.length; b++) a = 4 > b ? a + ('<div class="wrap' + f[b] + '"><div class="resize ' + f[b] + '" data-dir="' + f[b] + '"></div></div>') : a + ('<div class="resize ' + f[b] + '" data-dir="' + f[b] + '"></div>');
        this.getVals = function() {
            return {
                x: k,
                y: m,
                w: r,
                h: t,
                rotation: w
            }
        };
        this.setVals = h;
        this.constrainVals = function() {
            if (0 === w) {
                y = O.width();
                x = O.height();
                var a = k,
                    b = m,
                    n = r,
                    f = t;
                C ? (0 > a && (a = 0), 0 > b && (b = 0), n > y && (f *= y / n, n = y), f > x && (n *= x / f, f = x), a > y - n && (a = y - n), b > x - f && (b = x - f)) : (a + n < g && (a = g - n), b + f < g && (b = g - f), a > y - g && (a = y - g), b > x - g && (b = x - g));
                a === k && b === m && n === r && f === t || h(a, b, n, f, w)
            }
        };
        this.lockRatio = function() {
            G = r / t
        };
        this.toggleDrag = function(a) {
            Q = !!a
        };
        this.dragEnabled = function() {
            return Q
        };
        z.on("vmousedown", function(a) {
            Q && (q = 1, p(a))
        }).on("vmousedown", ".resize", function(a) {
            Q &&
                (q = $(this).hasClass("drag-rotate") ? 10 : f.indexOf($(this).attr("data-dir")) + 2, p(a))
        });
        z.append(a)
    };
    
    (function(a, b, c, d) {
        function h(a) {
            for (; a && "undefined" !== typeof a.originalEvent;) a = a.originalEvent;
            return a
        }

        function p(b) {
            for (var c = {}, d, e; b;) {
                d = a.data(b, k);
                for (e in d) d[e] && (c[e] = c.hasVirtualBinding = !0);
                b = b.parentNode
            }
            return c
        }

        function v() {
            J && (clearTimeout(J), J = 0);
            J = setTimeout(function() {
                x = J = 0;
                M.length = 0;
                N = !1;
                q = !0
            }, a.vmouse.resetTimerDuration)
        }

        function l(b, c, f) {
            var g, m;
            if (!(m = f && f[b])) {
                if (f = !f) a: for (f = c.target; f;) {
                    if ((m = a.data(f, k)) && (!b || m[b])) break a;
                    f = f.parentNode
                }
                m = f
            }
            if (m) {
                g =
                    c;
                f = g.type;
                var l, p;
                g = a.Event(g);
                g.type = b;
                b = g.originalEvent;
                m = a.event.props; - 1 < f.search(/^(mouse|click)/) && (m = t);
                if (b)
                    for (p = m.length, l; p;) l = m[--p], g[l] = b[l]; - 1 < f.search(/mouse(down|up)|click/) && !g.which && (g.which = 1);
                if (-1 !== f.search(/^touch/) && (l = h(b), f = l.touches, l = l.changedTouches, b = f && f.length ? f[0] : l && l.length ? l[0] : d))
                    for (f = 0, m = r.length; f < m; f++) l = r[f], g[l] = b[l];
                a(c.target).trigger(g)
            }
            return g
        }

        function D(b) {
            var c = a.data(b.target, m);
            N || x && x === c || !(c = l("v" + b.type, b)) || (c.isDefaultPrevented() && b.preventDefault(),
                c.isPropagationStopped() && b.stopPropagation(), c.isImmediatePropagationStopped() && b.stopImmediatePropagation())
        }

        function H(b) {
            var c = h(b).touches,
                d;
            c && 1 === c.length && (d = b.target, c = p(d), c.hasVirtualBinding && (x = y++, a.data(d, m, x), J && (clearTimeout(J), J = 0), A = q = !1, d = h(b).touches[0], G = d.pageX, P = d.pageY, l("vmouseover", b, c), l("vmousedown", b, c)))
        }

        function g(a) {
            q || (A || l("vmousecancel", a, p(a.target)), A = !0, v())
        }

        function Q(b) {
            if (!q) {
                var c = h(b).touches[0],
                    d = A,
                    e = a.vmouse.moveDistanceThreshold,
                    g = p(b.target);
                (A = A || Math.abs(c.pageX -
                    G) > e || Math.abs(c.pageY - P) > e) && !d && l("vmousecancel", b, g);
                l("vmousemove", b, g);
                v()
            }
        }

        function C(a) {
            if (!q) {
                q = !0;
                var b = p(a.target),
                    c;
                l("vmouseup", a, b);
                !A && (c = l("vclick", a, b)) && c.isDefaultPrevented() && (c = h(a).changedTouches[0], M.push({
                    touchID: x,
                    x: c.clientX,
                    y: c.clientY
                }), N = !0);
                l("vmouseout", a, b);
                A = !1;
                v()
            }
        }

        function z(b) {
            b = a.data(b, k);
            var c;
            if (b)
                for (c in b)
                    if (b[c]) return !0;
            return !1
        }

        function O() {}

        function L(b) {
            var c = b.substr(1);
            return {
                setup: function() {
                    z(this) || a.data(this, k, {});
                    a.data(this, k)[b] = !0;
                    w[b] = (w[b] ||
                        0) + 1;
                    1 === w[b] && F.bind(c, D);
                    a(this).bind(c, O);
                    E && (w.touchstart = (w.touchstart || 0) + 1, 1 === w.touchstart && F.bind("touchstart", H).bind("touchend", C).bind("touchmove", Q).bind("scroll", g))
                },
                teardown: function() {
                    --w[b];
                    w[b] || F.unbind(c, D);
                    E && (--w.touchstart, w.touchstart || F.unbind("touchstart", H).unbind("touchmove", Q).unbind("touchend", C).unbind("scroll", g));
                    var d = a(this),
                        e = a.data(this, k);
                    e && (e[b] = !1);
                    d.unbind(c, O);
                    z(this) || d.removeData(k)
                }
            }
        }
        var k = "virtualMouseBindings",
            m = "virtualTouchID";
        b = "vmouseover vmousedown vmousemove vmouseup vclick vmouseout vmousecancel".split(" ");
        var r = "clientX clientY pageX pageY screenX screenY".split(" "),
            t = a.event.props.concat(a.event.mouseHooks ? a.event.mouseHooks.props : []),
            w = {},
            J = 0,
            G = 0,
            P = 0,
            A = !1,
            M = [],
            N = !1,
            q = !1,
            E = "addEventListener" in c,
            F = a(c),
            y = 1,
            x = 0,
            K;
        a.vmouse = {
            moveDistanceThreshold: 10,
            clickDistanceThreshold: 10,
            resetTimerDuration: 1500
        };
        for (var R = 0; R < b.length; R++) a.event.special[b[R]] = L(b[R]);
        E && c.addEventListener("click", function(b) {
            var c = M.length,
                d = b.target,
                e, g, h, k, l;
            if (c)
                for (e = b.clientX, g = b.clientY, K = a.vmouse.clickDistanceThreshold,
                    h = d; h;) {
                    for (k = 0; k < c; k++)
                        if (l = M[k], h === d && Math.abs(l.x - e) < K && Math.abs(l.y - g) < K || a.data(h, m) === l.touchID) {
                            b.preventDefault();
                            b.stopPropagation();
                            return
                        }
                    h = h.parentNode
                }
        }, !0)
    })(jQuery, d, aa);
})(window, document, $w, $d);

(function() {
    var f = $("#ic-cropper-wrap"),
        h = $("#ic-info"),
        b, d;
        
    $d.on("change", "#ic-upload-btn input", function(a) {
        f.empty();
        var c = Math.min(600, $("#ic-main").width());
        b = new ImageCropper(f, c, c);
        b.setMoveCallback(function() {
            var a = b.getVals();
            h.text(a.w + "w X " + a.h + "h (x:" + a.x + ", y:" + a.y + ")")
        });
        d = a.target.files[0];
        a = new FileReader;
        a.onload = function(a) {
            b.setSrc(a.target.result);
            $(".ic-hidden.ic-crop-btn-wrap").removeClass("ic-hidden");
        };
        a.readAsDataURL(d);
    });
    
    $d.on("click", "#ic-crop-btn", function() {
        if (!b) return !1;
        $(".ic-hidden.ic-result-wrap").removeClass("ic-hidden");
        var a = "image/png" === $("#ic-download-type").val() ? "image/png" : "image/jpeg",
            c = b.getFinalDataUrl(a);
            $(".theresult").html('<img class="result-image" src="' + c + '" style="width: ' + $(".icrop-clip-wrap").width() + 'px" />'); 
           $(".ic-hidden.ic-download-wrap").removeClass("ic-hidden");
      });
    
    $d.on("click", "#ic-download-btn", function() {
        if (!b) return !1;
        
        var a = "image/png" === $("#ic-download-type").val() ? "image/png" : "image/jpeg",
            c = $(".theresult img").attr("src");
            
        if (window.URL && URL.createObjectURL && window.Uint8Array && window.Blob) {
            for (var e =
                    c, c = 0 <= e.split(",")[0].indexOf("base64") ? atob(e.split(",")[1]) : unescape(e.split(",")[1]), e = e.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0], f = new Uint8Array(c.length), g = 0; g < c.length; g++) f[g] = c.charCodeAt(g);
            c = new Blob([f], {
                type: e
            });
            c = URL.createObjectURL(c)
        }
        this.href = c;
        this.download = a = (d ? d.name.split(".")[0] + "_cropped" : "cropped_image") + ("image/png" === a ? ".png" : ".jpg");
    });
    $d.on("click", "#ic-rotate-btn", function() {
        b && b.rotateClockwise();
    });
    $d.on("click", "#ic-flip-btn", function() {
        b && b.flipHorizontal();
    });
    
    // OPEN THE MODAL
    $(".cropper").show();
    $d.on('click', ".open-modal", function(event){
        $(".cropper").show();
    });
    $d.on('click', ".close-modal", function(event){
        $(".cropper").hide();
    });
})();
```