# How to crop an image when height limit is reached? using html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, sass

i have an image that is kind of large and in order for it to not take up all the screen on wider devices i want it to appear cropped from the top and bottom when a certain height limit is reached, e.g. 600px. This isnt a problem on smaller, narrower screens since the image scales down and doesnt cover the other parts of my webapp. thanks in advance!

this is what ive currently got:

HTML:

```
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="../../assets/home_image1.jpg" alt="bg image of airplane" class="background-image" />
    <div class="text-overlay">
      <h1>Universal Tours</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.text-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Optional background color */
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff; /* Text color */
  border-radius: 5px; /* Optional border-radius */
}
```

ive tried height limit but it shrinks the image keeping the aspect ratio, and that leaves empty space around it and doesnt look very good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crop the image using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810434/crop-the-image-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CSS property `object-fit: cover;` along with setting a maximum height.

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden; /* hides extra parts of image */
  max-height: 600px; /* max height */
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /* sets height = 100% of the container */
  object-fit: cover; /* will make sure image covers the area and is cropped */ 
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Is there a way to select what parts of the image are cropped, or rather covered, when the windowsize changes? Ideally using only CSS, but if it's too complicated that's fine too thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CSS [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) property and [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

```css
img.fitted {
/* tells the image to cover it's container without distorting the aspect ratio */
  object-fit: cover;
  /* tells the image to position the center of the image at the center of the container */
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Original</h2>
<img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp6599760.jpg" width=400 />

<h2>Clipped to max height of 300px (without crop)</h2>
<img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp6599760.jpg" width=400 height=300 />

<h2>Clipped to max height of 300px (with crop)</h2>
<img class="fitted" src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp6599760.jpg" width=400 height=300 />
```