# To cut out the image in Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas, blob

I have image in Canvas.

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
canvas.width = 640
canvas.height = 480
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
element.appendChild(canvas)
const imageData = context.createImageData(640, 480)
imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(data.frame))
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
```

I receive data (height, width, x, y).
I want to cut an image from the canvas according to this data and save it as a blob-file.
How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015497/how-to-resize-then-crop-an-image-with-canvas (at least for the cutting-out part; how to get a blob of that after, is something you should be able to research yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is unclear. The code example does not match the problem descriptions. As the code example does not work (undefined variable `data`) I can only go by the description of the problem.

> I receive data (height, width, x, y). I want to cut an image from the canvas according to this data and save it as a blob-file. How can I do this?

### To cut from Image

To cut a rectangular area from a canvas

```
function cutArea(fromImage, x, y, width, height) {
    const cut = document.createElement("canvas");
    cut.width = width;
    cut.height = height;
    const ctx = cut.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(fromImage, -x, -y);
    return cut;
}
```

You should use an offscreenCanvas but support is limited so add it if you know what your targets are. To create an offscreenCanvas cut

```
function cutArea(fromImage, x, y, width, height) {
    const cut = new OffscreenCanvas(width, height);
    const ctx = cut.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(fromImage, -x, -y);
    return cut;
}
```

Note

- That the pixel scale is unchanged and that there is not bounds checks. Part or all of the cut image may be empty (0 alpha) if the coordinated do not lay on the image source.
- `fromImage` can be any valid image source, including a canvas.
- `width` and `height` must be > 0 or the functions will throw an error.

### Download

To download the cut to local store as downloaded "image/png" image file. Note filename can be changed by user on download. The image type is the default `png`. There is no way to know if download is successful.

```
function downloadCut(cut, name) {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.download = name + ".png"; 
    const download = blob => {
        const url = a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click", {view: window, bubbles: true, cancelable: true})); 
        setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(url), 1000); // clean up 
    }
    if (cut instanceof OffscreenCanvas) { cut.convertToBlob().then(download) }
    else { canvas.toBlob(download) }
}
```