# Retrieve a piece of image from X Y and Width Height coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to take a part of an image (the crop).
I can select the place I want to crop, but I don't know how to "cut" this part of the image to keep it in a variable.

I have an object like :

```
unit: "px"
height: 54
width: 144
x: 278
y: 219
```

Have you an idea on how can I 'cut' this part to create a new image ?

Comment: You can use canvases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015497/how-to-resize-then-crop-an-image-with-canvas

Comment: what did you try so far?