# Can I transform images without uploading them to cloudinary?

Tags: javascript, c#, cloudinary

Currently I'm using different transforms on an image on my server before I save it to cloudinary

ex. width, height, crop, gravity

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
   var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
          File = new FileDescription(file.Name, stream),
          Transformation = new Transformation()
             .Width(500).Height(500).Crop("fill").Gravity("face")
    };
                
    uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
}
```

but I was wondering if it was possible to do Cloudinary transforms of the image to see what the image will look like without uploading it first? Specifically, .Crop("fill").Gravity("face")

This way I can display it to the user and they can either accept or reject it before saving it to my Cloudinary account and my server.

- just to be specific, I'm looking for a Cloudinary solution, not a 3rd party JS lib, unless it does Gravity("face") and is small in size

Thanks for any help

Comment: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520932-Is-there-an-offline-applications-testing-option-using-Cloudinary-s-API-

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the info from this link, but from what I've read I don't think it provides me with a transformed image without uploading it first.

Answer (score 1):

For the cropping/resizing part you can do it without a library, all you need is a canvas, this link may help you [How to resize then crop an image with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015497/how-to-resize-then-crop-an-image-with-canvas)

For the `Gravity("face")` part, that's another level of engineering, you need an AI to detect and locate all the faces withing the picture, you have to use a library and [face-api.js](http://justadudewhohacks%20/%20face-api.js) is just the best solution for javascript, its only down side is its size "we're talking about megabytes" here is the [demo](https://justadudewhohacks.github.io/face-api.js/) page

If you want something much lighter and faster, but less accurate "compared to face-api.js" there is [pico.js](https://github.com/tehnokv/picojs), here is the [demo](https://tehnokv.com/posts/picojs-intro/demo/) page

Either way, Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the input. I think I'll go in a different direction. This is for a form wizard for the user profile (social net site). The last step in the form is the user image. I'm using ng2-file-upload to get the image from the user and I want to show the img on the screen as a thumb before it gets uploaded and saved to Cloudinary. So if the user doesn't like it he/she can upload a new one to use. But I need to run it through the transformations and upload it in cloudinary first to get the img url to pass back to the form to show the image.

Comment: So I think what I'll do is once they've uploaded it in the onboarding form wizard I won't give them the ability to re upload. If they want to change the image, they can do it in their profile edit page.

Comment: I dont know how cloudnary work, but take a look a this " https://pqina.nl/doka/ " ... to be honest a don't think you need a face detection system just to crop an image, just let the user crop there pictures them selfs, it give them more control over the final result and all you need is to upload the final result only once.

Comment: Ya this is similar to cropperjs, but this one isn't free. THere's no way I'm paying  for that...

Comment: Sorry didn't see the price tag, I was absorbed by the details ...  in that case go ahead with your solution, seems like a good compromise. good luck :)